# How to get the contents of an array to display on a uitextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, uitextview

I'm trying to get the contents of an array to display on a uitextfield.

here's my code:

```
NSArray *arrayConditions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[item objectForKey:@"conditions"], nil];

NSString * resultConditions = [arrayConditions description];
```

// conditionsDeal is the uitextfield
       self.conditionsDeal.text = resultConditions;

conditions are being pulled from a url like this:

```
"results": [
{
  "conditions": [
    "Il coupon è valido per soggiorni fino al...",
    "I coupon sono cumulabili, possibilità...",
    "Coupon non cumulabile con altre promozioni...",
  ],
  "deadline": "2013-11-27T22:59:59.000Z",
```

Currently the only thing that displays in my uitextview is:

[image]

I need to remove the ( (  ) ) parentheses and format it neatly.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to join all the strings in the array like this:

```
self.conditionsDeal.text = [arrayConditions[@"conditions"] componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@" "];
```