# How to display an NSArray in a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, uitextview

I have a array that's I want to have in a uitextview. This is how it's currently displaying. How do I remove the ( ( ) )'s?

Here's a screenshot

[image]

Here's my code:

```
NSArray *arrayConditions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[item objectForKey:@"conditions"], nil];

NSString * resultConditions = [arrayConditions description];

self.conditionsDeal.text = resultConditions;

NSLog(@"conditions are %@", [item objectForKey:@"conditions"]);
```

thanks for any help

Comment: In other words.. you want us to give you a better formatting for displaying an array?

Comment: `NSString *_string = [_yourArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"]; // or any other string`

Comment: duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341256/how-to-get-the-contents-of-an-array-to-display-on-a-uitextfield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *arrayConditions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[item objectForKey:@"conditions"], nil];

// change this line only for the concatenation
NSString * resultConditions = [arrayConditions componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];

self.conditionsDeal.text = resultConditions;

// this line always provides you the result of the '-description' method of the 'NSArray'
NSLog(@"conditions are %@", [item objectForKey:@"conditions"]);
```

Comment: for new folks (me), can change output from one item per line, to separate items by comma by change @"\n" to @", "  (thank you holex)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableString *textViewText = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSString *str in arrayConditions)
    [textViewText appendFormat:@"%@\n", str];
self.conditionsDeal.text = textViewText;
```

Comment: what is wrong with the `-componentsJoinedByString:` method? :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert that array into NSMutableString.
2. Separate that string by "," or space and write it UITextView.